# Files stored to public folder get reset node js

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

In my node js application I am turning user data entered through a form into a js object and then storing that js object as a json file in the public folder of my ejs server. This works all well locally on my computer however when I use Heroku all the files that get stored into the server from form requests reset after a while.

Below is what I'm going to store json files

```
fs.writeFile(
    __dirname + "/public/" + "AddonPosts/" + addonFromFile.name + ".json",
    JSON.stringify(addonFromFile),
    function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
    }
  );
```

Is there any way to write to my server without it constantly resetting? Additionally would there be an easy way to then download that folder I have written to?

Thanks

Comment: see https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted

Answer (score 0):

heroku Free tier does not save the files that are uploaded/Newly Created when your app is running. It resets your app to the stage how it was uploaded.

In short, dynamic uploads/Saving are not possible.

Alternative way: Use mongodb atalas[Free 500mb] to store your data